# Can I rewrite url only internally and not change the url in the address bar?

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am currently using

`RewriteRule ^(.*)wordpress(.*) $1wp-oct/live$2`

to remap my test install at `www/wp-oct/live/` to `http://localhost/wordpress/`

And it does the job but it also changes the url in the addressbar as `http://localhost/wp-oct/live`

Is there a way to keep the url in the addressbar `http://localhost/wordpress/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to use `mod_proxy` for this instead of rewriting:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  ProxyRequests Off

  <proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </proxy>

  ProxyPass /wordpress http://localhost/wp-oct/live
  ProxyPassReverse /wordpress http://localhost/wp-oct/live
</IfModule>
```